# Return array from Nusoap(undefined index)

Tags: php

im trying to create NuSOAP WS with php , but when i deploy my application
into my device i can't get data from my WS and and get this message from the server :

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in ...\lib\nusoap.php on line 6637
```

When i test my method from SOAPUI i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx8gu.png).

When i test my method from Http Analyser i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXw4X.png).

I think there is a bug in nusoap.php that add automatically the tag "item" for each array element but i can't resolve it.

Some of the method :

```
$notifications = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $notification=new Notification();
     $notification->titre=$row['titre'];
     $notification->detail=$row['detail'];
     $notification->dateHeure=$row[date];
     $notification->code=$row['code'];
    array_push($notifications,$notification);
}
return $notifications;
```

Comment: Can you show the line to us on which got this error?

Comment: $this->soapresponse = $this->message[$this->root_struct]['result'];